# Installing sharp on AWS using CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, sharp

While installing dependencies through codepipeline I am getting error during running of Afterinstall hook lifecycle event.

error :

```
LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - AfterInstallHook.sh
[stderr]npm ERR! code 1
[stderr]npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/node_modules/sharp
[stderr]npm ERR! command failed
[stderr]npm ERR! command sh -c -- (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
[stderr]npm ERR! sharp: Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
[stderr]npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
[stderr]npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'
[stderr]
[stderr]npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr]npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-23T12_14_07_445Z-debug-0.log
```

Tried to remove all node_modules and re installing but didn't work.
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CodeDeploy uses root when running hooks. The console output indicates that you'll have to run npm with the `--unsafe-perm` flag to be able to execute the script as root.

As an alternative, you might consider using `runas` within the AppSpec file for CodeDeploy to specify the user that the hook is executed under.

Note that it will be easier to help you if you provide additional information such as the [CodeDeploy log file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html).